# Random numbers only some times

Tags: java

How can I get a random number x% of the time

```
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

and y% of the times any number above  10.

Maybe trivial but I can not find a simple solution
Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: What's a "random number" vs. "any number above 10"?

Comment: max is less then 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you use a random number generator. Most of those return a number in the interval [0,1] so you would then check whether that number is <= x(percentage/chance) or not. Following is the sample code

```
double x=0.1;
if( Math.random() <= x ) {
   int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
}
```

here i choose the chance of x to be 10% i.e 0.1. so for 10% of cases you will get a random number. you can do vice versa for y as well as per your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your `x` applied randomly, or deterministic?

**Random variant:**

If you want `x` to also be random, you can just generate a random value:

```
int percent = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 100);
if (percent < x) {
    // ...get the actual random value.
}
```

`percent` should be between 1 and 100, so you have exactly 100 possible values. If you include `0`, you have 101. Then you do your percentage check. If percent is outside (larger than) `x`, `x` was too small. Therefore you get a `false`, otherwise a `true`. From there you can work with an `if`-condition.

**Deterministic variant:**

If deterministic, it depends on your preferred behavior. For example, you could use a counter and every time you pass above 100, you 'break' and return true:

```
// object attribute.
private Integer accumulator = 0;

// in method (should be synchronized, at least on accumulator, if you use multithreading):
accumulator += x;
boolean overflow = false;
if (accumulator >= 100) {
    overflow = true;
    accumulator %= 100; // this applies modulo 100 to accumulator.
}

if (overflow) {
    // ...get the actual random value.
}
```

With this, you will get exactly `x` percent of `true`s, the more you call your method. In the beginning you will have none, unless 100%, but over time, the accuracy rises.